# can a data be sent when change page [pagination]

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I want to view data sort by date the user input by using pagination.

This is how my query looks like:

```html
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id), BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime 
               FROM `order` WHERE YEAR(DateTime)= $Year AND MONTH(DateTime) = $Month") 
or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime 
         FROM `order` WHERE YEAR(DateTime)= $Year AND 
         MONTH(DateTime) = $Month LIMIT $start, $per_page")
or die(mysql_error());
```

When I click the next page its shows error. when i just run the query without the `WHERE` the pagination works great. Any suggestion how to solve this would be great.

This is the whole pagination code:

```html
<?php

include('../include/conn.php');
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$Month = $_GET ['Month'];
$Year = $_GET ['Year'];
$per_page = 5;
$adjacents = 6; 

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id), BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime 
FROM `order`") 
or die(mysql_error());

//get total number of pages to be shown from  total result
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

//get current page from URL ,if not present set it to 1
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1 ;

//calcuproduct_namee actual start page with respect to Mysql 
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

//execute a mysql query to retrieve  all result from current page by using LIMIT keyword in mysql
//if  query  fails stop further execution and show mysql error

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime FROM `order` 
WHERE YEAR(DateTime)= $Year AND MONTH(DateTime) = $Month LIMIT $start, $per_page")
         or die(mysql_error());

$pagination="Pagination";
//if current page is first show first only else reduce 1 by current page
$Prev_Page = ($page==1)?1:$page - 1;

//if current page is last show last  only else add  1 to  current page
$Next_Page = ($page>=$pages)?$page:$page + 1; 

//if we are not on first page show first link
if($page!=1) $pagination.= '<a href="?page=1">First</a>';
//if we are not on first page show previous link
if($page!=1) $pagination.='<a href="?page='.$Prev_Page.'">Previous</a>';

//we are going to display 5 links on pagination bar
$numberoflinks=5;

//find the number of links to show on right of current page
$upage=ceil(($page)/$numberoflinks)*$numberoflinks;
//find the number of links to show on left of current page
$lpage=floor(($page)/$numberoflinks)*$numberoflinks;
//if  number of links on left of current page are zero we start from 1
$lpage=($lpage==0)?1:$lpage;
//find the number of links to show on right of current page and make sure it must be less than total number of pages
$upage=($lpage==$upage)?$upage+$numberoflinks:$upage;
if($upage>$pages)$upage=($pages-1);
//start building links from left to right of current page
for($x=$lpage; $x<=$upage; $x++){
//if current building link is current page we don't show link,we show as text else we show as linkn 
$pagination.=($x == $page) ? ' <strong>'.$x.'</strong>' : ' <a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>' ;
}
//we show next link and last link if user doesn't on last page
if($page!=$pages) $pagination.=  '  <a href="?page='.$Next_Page.'">Next</a>';
if($page!=$pages) $pagination.=  ' <a href="?page='.$pages.'">Last</a>';


?>
```

When I hit the next button, it fails to get the `$Month` and `$Year`.

How can I send the data to page 2 of the search?

Comment: Its show error?? Can you show us what error it show?? And why not quotes around your `$Month` and `$Year`

Comment: Can you show the part of code who makes pagination please ?

Comment: Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add in the pagination link to include Year and Month, like:

   < a href="?Year='.$Year.'&Month='.$Month.'&page='.$x.'">

which of course, the value has to be supplied. They don't look like they are set in your code. So, make them like:

```
$Month = isset($_GET ['Month']) ? $_GET ['Month'] : '1';
$Year = isset($_GET['Year']) ? $_GET ['Year'] : '2015';
```

2. Try escape the $year and $month before using them in the query string:

   $Month = mysql_real_escape_string($Month);
   $Year = mysql_real_escape_string($Year);

If above fails, try echo and execute the result in sql query to debug:

```
echo "SELECT id, BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,DateTime FROM `order` 
WHERE YEAR(DateTime)= $Year AND MONTH(DateTime) = $Month LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

Comment: i just add the link include for year and month in pagination and it works like a charm:D